# How do I change my Google Map function from auto finding my location, to making me type in a location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, api

Currently I have a working map that can automatically find my location using the "Find Me" button I added.  I would like to change this to instead having a form where the user could type in any location.  How would I go about changing that?  I'm a total beginner, thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <a href="#" id="get_location">Find Me</a>
    <div id="map">
        <iframe id="google_map" width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk?output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script>
        var c = function (pos) {
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude,
                long = pos.coords.longitude,
                coords = lat + ', ' + long;

            document.getElementById('google_map').setAttribute('src', 'https://maps.google.co.uk/?q=' + coords + '&z=60&output=embed');
        }

        document.getElementById('get_location').onclick = function () {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(c);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this [Google Map example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) is more or less what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work using a link as a button as you did:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map">
        <iframe id="google_map" width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk?output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>

    <form>
    Latitude:<br>
    <input type="text" id="latitude"><br>
    Longitude:<br>
    <input type="text" id="longitude">
    </form>
    <a href="#" id="get_location">Find This</a>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('get_location').onclick = function () {
            var lat = document.getElementById('latitude').value
            var long = document.getElementById('longitude').value
            coords = lat + ', ' + long; 

            document.getElementById('google_map').setAttribute('src', 'https://maps.google.co.uk/?q=' + coords + '&z=60&output=embed');
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```